# How to create an all browser-compatible hanging indent style in CSS in a span

Tags: html, css, indentation

The only thing I've found has been;

```css
.hang {
    text-indent: -3em;
    margin-left: 3em;
}
```

The only way for this to work is putting text in a paragraph, which causes those horribly unsightly extra lines. I'd much rather just have them in a `<span class="hang"></span>` type of thing.

I'm also looking for a way to further indent than just a single-level of hanging. Using paragraphs to stack the indentions doesn't work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`<span>` is an inline element. The term *hanging indent* is meaningless unless you're talking about a paragraph (which generally means a block element). You can, of course, change the margins on `<p>` or `<div>` or any other block element to get rid of extra vertical space between paragraphs.

You may want something like `display: run-in`, where the tag will become either block or inline depending on context... sadly, this is [not yet universally supported by browsers](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html).

Comment: The simples approach would be to use the `.hang` css on a div, which is basically the same as a span, but as a block element instead of inline text. Optionally, you could include `display:block;` in the `.hang` definition, but then again using span for this would be same as using div...

Answer (score 12):

Found a cool  way to do just that, minus the nasty span.

```css
p {
  padding-left: 20px; 
} 

p:first-letter {
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

Nice and simple :D

If the newlines are bothering you in p blocks, you can add

```css
p {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/agweber/9dmtfhw2/)

Comment: I think you mean ":first-child"

Comment: I don't think it would be ":first-child".  Not sure if ":first-letter" will get it done either.  It didn't work in my tests.  Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp) says margin properties can be used with `:first-letter`

Comment: I created the following [link](jsfiddle.net/David_Barnett/UqHQv/). The only drawback I've found to this method is that when selecting text, the first-letter is often not select-able.

Comment: or just use `p { text-indent:-20px; padding-left:20px }`

Answer (score 3):

ysth's answer is best with one debatable exception; the unit of measure should correspond to the size of the font.

```css
p {
  text-indent: -2en; 
  padding-left: 2en;
}
```

"3" would also work adequately well; "em" is not recommended as it is wider than the average character in an alphabetic set. "px" should only be used if you intended to align hangs of text blocks with differing font sizes.

Comment: Tested in chrome and it doesn't like _en_. Googling _en vs em_ shows up as a dash-specific character width, nothing says I can use it for spacing.

Comment: Rather than _en_, use _ch_, which is defined as the width of an average character in a font; _em_ is defined as the width of the widest character in a font.