# How can I replicate a <ol><li> bullet list in HTML with indents that line up correctly?

Tags: html, css, google-sites

I need an HTML alphabetical bulleted list which will be used quite frequently. This is something that is not supported with Google sites, which I use all the time for work...can you manually replicate a HTML bulleted list?

So far my indents don't match up because I am using fixed margins and the alphabetical characters all have unique dimensions in pixels:

```html
<div style="display:inline">
<b style="text-align:left">Enter your list title here</b>
<span style="display:block;margin-left:40px"> 
<p style="font-size:0.85em;font-weight:normal"><b style="margin-right:1em">a.</b>Enter your list description here</p>
<p style="font-size:0.85em;font-weight:normal"><b style="margin-right:1em">b.</b>Enter your list description here</p>
<p style="font-size:0.85em;font-weight:normal"><b style="margin-right:1em">c.</b>Enter your list description here</p>
<p style="font-size:0.85em;font-weight:normal"><b style="margin-right:1em">d.</b>Enter your list description here</p>
<p style="font-size:0.85em;font-weight:normal"><b style="margin-right:1em">e.</b>Enter your list description here</p>
<p style="font-size:0.85em;font-weight:normal"><b style="margin-right:1em">f.</b>Enter your list description here</p>
<p style="font-size:0.85em;font-weight:normal"><b style="margin-right:1em">g.</b>Enter your list description here</p>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: a bulleted list is just a hanging indent, mostly... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809/how-to-create-an-all-browser-compatible-hanging-indent-style-in-css-in-a-span

Comment: seems lined up here...

Comment: Sure a hanging indent, but surely that indent is calculated for each line, because they are always perfectly neat indents all lined up properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Google Sites have some limitations, I'm not sure if you're using a [HTML Box](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/2500646) or editing the [HTML source](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/153196) of the Google Page, but you can use the  `HTML style attribute` with following syntax:

```html
<ol style="list-style-type:lower-alpha">
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
  <li>item4</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't think to use the HTML Box gadget. This has worked. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ol type="a">
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
</ol>
```

Ordered Lists already supports various methods for how the list is defined (Numbers, alphabet, roman numerals, etc).  This can also be modified using CSS `list-style-type`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type

Comment: Hi, thanks but I already tried that - it just isn't supported in Google sites :(

Comment: If Google Sites won't let you specify `<ol type="a">` you can always use the `list-style-type` attribute: `ol { list-style-type: lower-alpha; }`.  Unless Google Sites prohibits your adding custom CSS?

Comment: Hi, Robert, yeah Google strips out all that block level stuff and most custom CSS. It only likes some inline CSS styles.

Comment: Have you checked out https://support.google.com/sites/answer/2500646?hl=en ?  This seems to suggest there is a way to add custom CSS/JS to your site.